# Openssl input string instead of file using python

Tags: python, openssl

I have the following openssl command which gets the URL from a CRL from a certificate.

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in cert.pem | grep -A 4 'X509v3 CRL Distribution Points'"
```

Instead of an input ofx509 certificate, can I give a string with ----Beginn Certificate,... as input?

I did not get any result of my trys. So pls help me :=)